# How to get Candlesstick Hi-low Value on Heaiknashi Chart

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am new to pinescript and trying to Create ORB (opening range breakout) for 15 min.
But here i want to keep chart of Heaiknashi, but when i keep chart of heaiknashi, it plots hi-low of heaiknashi candle. but i want to plot actual Hi-low of 5 min candlestick on Heaiknashi chart.
i search but no success, if anyone knows about it. it will be great help. Thanks in advance.
complete code as below

```
study(title="ORB15 ", shorttitle="ORB15", overlay=true)
up15 = input(true, title="15 Minute Opening Range High")
down15 = input(true, title="15 Minute Opening Range Low")

is_newbar(res) => change(time(res)) != 0 

adopt(r, s) => security(tickerid, r, s) 

high_range = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),high,0)
low_range = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),low,0)

high_rangeL = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),high,0) 
low_rangeL = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),low,0) 

up15 = plot(up15on ? adopt('15', high_rangeL): na, color = #009900, linewidth=2) 
down15 = plot(down15on ? adopt('15', low_rangeL): na, color = #ff0000, linewidth=2) 

trans15 = up15 ?  97 : 100
fill(up15, down15, color = white, transp=trans15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to get the regular 15min high/low data on your HA chart:

```
[h,l] = security(tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker), "15", [high,low]) 

plot(h)
plot(l)
```

Cheers, and have a great day

Comment: Thanks, it worked well

Comment: Take care Prashant!